# Why do we need Paint to draw an integer array of colors as a bitmap in android?

Tags: android, paint, android-canvas

Forgive me if I'm overlooking something, but I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere.  In android, a canvas has a method to draw an array of integers as a bitmap:

```
void     drawBitmap(int[] colors, int offset, int stride,
                    int x, int y, int width, int height,
                    boolean hasAlpha, Paint paint)
```

I understand every argument being passed to this method except for the last one.  Why would it need any "Paint" information when it is getting the exact information it needs to render the bitmap from the integer array passed as "colors"?

Is there any difference in the results if we use different paints?  If so, what?  Does it have anything to do with pseudo-pixel <==> real-pixel transformations (such as anti-aliasing?) If so, what kind of performance impact does this (and/or other paint properties have?

Also (bonus question) is there anyway to instantiate a new paint object with desired properties, or does this always require several lines of code? (yes, see below)

**Edit**: I learned that a paint object can be instantiated with flags:

```
private Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG + Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG + Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is a function called from inside the drawBitmap method.

```
native_drawBitmap(mNativeCanvas, colors, offset, stride, x, y, width, height, hasAlpha,
            paint != null ? paint.mNativePaint : 0);
```

As you can see, even if you send null, 0 is passed. The above code makes a call to the skia framework.

From what I understand, the paint object is used to handle differences of density between canvas,bitmap and the screen.

Comment: To clarify, from this code it would seem that passing null for paint would result in the value '0' being passed as that argument to the native_drawBitmap function (which I would guess is some sensible default).  Do you know if there are significant performance penalties/benefits?

Comment: Oh didnt notice the '!='. I dont know about the performance difference. You might need to run some tests or maybe someone else will have the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* it, Paint can be null.

It's there most likely so you can use the colorFilter or maskFilter properties of Paint as they would be applied to your colors.

Comment: Do you know what kind of performance impact that various paint choices would have, if any?  Or is this something that is done in hardware and thus not worth thinking about?